# proof that $\frac{a+b}{2ab}$ is not an integer (with both $a$ and $b$ belonging to $N$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was solving another question using the recursion method, then I got stuck because I can't prove that $\frac{a+b}{2ab}$ is not an integer.
Any hints will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If $a=b=1,$ then $(a+b)/2ab=1 \in \mathbb N.$

Comment: If $a \ne1$ or $b \ne 1$, then $a(b-1)+b(a-1) >0.$ Can you proceed ?

Comment: If $a>1$ and $b>1$, then $1/(2a)<1/2$ and $1/(2b)<1/2$.

Comment: Consider the product $(2a-1)(2b-1)=2[2ab-(a+b)]+1$.

Comment: @Fred I don't really understand how can that help me...can you please explain a bit more? Thank you very much

Comment: @Joe I understand that 1/2ab is smaller than 1/2 but it does it necessarly mean that (a+b)/2ab is smaller than 1? If so, can you please explain more. Thank you very much

Comment: From $a(b-1)+b(a-1) >0$ we get $2ab > a+b$, hence $0<(a+b)/2ab<1 .$

Comment: @OscarLanzi I'm afraid that I was unable to move on with the product that you have provided. Can you please explain in more detail? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Fred Oh. It took me a while to understand. But now I get it. Thank you very much for your help! Now I can continue my assignment. Thank you once again

Comment: $$\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b\le 2.$$

Comment: I didn't write that $1/2ab<1/2$, I wrote that $1/(2a)<1/2$ and $1/(2b)<1/2$. That means their sum is less than one.

Comment: @Joe OHH Now I get it! Thank you very much for explaining your method. It will be of much use in my demonstration. Thank you once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously when $a=b=1, \dfrac{a+b}{2ab} =1\in N$.
For other cases, WLOG, assume that $$1\leq a\leq b,$$
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\textrm{ then }2 a \leq a+b \leqslant 2 b \\
\displaystyle 0<\frac{1}{b}=\frac{2 a}{2 a b} \leqslant \frac{a+b}{2 a b} \leqslant \frac{2 b}{2 a b}=\frac{1}{a}\leq 1
\end{array}
$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{a+b}{2 a b}\textrm{  is never an integer
unless }a=b=1.$$

Comment: Your demonstration is very good and easy to understand. I only have one question: are you sure that I can assume that: 2a≤a+b⩽2b? And Thank you very much for your help Lai!

Comment: See the new version please.

Comment: Ah! Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you once again for your help! Now I can continue my assignment. Thanks again!